# Efficiently getting the most recent data given an "as-of date"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some data which may be represented thusly:

```
CREATE TABLE #foo (
    id INT
  , year INT
  , value INT
  , date Date
)

INSERT INTO #foo (id, year, value, date)
VALUES (1, 1, 1, '2001-01-01')
     , (1, 2, 2, '2002-01-01')
     , (1, 2, 3, '2002-02-01')
     , (1, 2, 2, '2003-03-01') -- a year later!
     , (1, 3, 2, '2003-01-01')
     , (1, 3, 2, '2003-03-01')
```

Basically, I have financial data on some companies identified by IDs (in this case, just a single company is shown). This data comes from disclosures companies make from time to time, and I have the year the financial data is associated with and the date of the relevant financial report.

Note that I might have more than one report for a given year. This is because companies might notice there are mistakes in what they've previously reported and submit "restatements" correcting those inaccuracies. In some cases, those corrections can come a long time after the fact, even after results from the next period have been handed in (as in this case, where the last report for Year 2 comes after the first report for Year 3).

Now, I want to identify the data I would know at any given date in the past. This obviously involves filtering out anything given after that date, but also discarding any "outdated" reports which have since been corrected (by restatements prior to my "as of date").

The best I've done is: (the use of `*` is just for this question, I swear)

```
SELECT id, year, value, date
FROM (
    SELECT *
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, year
                              ORDER BY date DESC) AS recency
    FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM #foo
        WHERE date <= '2002-02-01'
        ) x
) y
WHERE recency = 1

-- | id | year | value |    date    |
-- |----|------|-------|------------|
-- |  1 |    1 |     1 | 2001-01-01 |
-- |  1 |    2 |     3 | 2002-02-01 |
```

This starts by discarding everything prior to my as-of date (2002-02-01), and then uses the number of rows in each (id, year) pair to identify the most recent report.

This works just fine, but having to use three queries (one plus two subqueries) to do this seems clumsy. Is this correct or is there some technique I'm unaware of to do this more elegantly?

Comment: `*` is fine how you have it anyway so no need for the disclaimer! There is no problem with using it in derived tables and CTEs as long as the outer select only projects the needed columns.

Answer (score 0):

`ROW_NUMBER()` is probably the simplest solution:

```
select f.*
from (select f.*,
             row_number() over (partition by f.id, f.year order by f.date desc) as seqnum
      from #foo f
      where f.date <= @date
     ) f
where seqnum = 1;
```

This is essentially the same as your version performance-wise.

Comment: Ah, so `row_number` is actually generated after the `where` filter! I'd thought of this solution, but thought it'd fail by giving the last Year 2 statement (in 2003, after my `@date`) `seqnum = 1`.

Comment: @Wasabi . . . Yes.  The execution plan of this code and of your code should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could start by eliminating a superfluous level in your query:

```
SELECT id, year, value, date
FROM (
    SELECT *
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, year
                              ORDER BY date DESC) AS recency
    FROM #foo
    WHERE date <= '2002-02-01'
) y
WHERE recency = 1
```

Another way to phrase this is to use a correlated subquery for filtering:

```
select f.*
from #foo f
where f.date = (select min(f1.date) from #foo f1 where f1.id = f.id and f1.year = f.year)
```

For the second query, you want an index on `(id, year, date)`.

Comment: As I commented beneath Gordon's answer, I thought `row_number()` was populated prior to the `where` filter, in which case this would fail since it'd give `recency = 1` to the 2003 report of Year 2, not the 2002-02-01 report.

Comment: @Wasabi: no, the `where` clause is evaluated first, before the `select` clause.